# For which values of $\alpha$ is the function $f(x,y,z)=\frac{\ln(1+x^2y^4z^6)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\alpha}}$ differentiable?

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ defined by

$$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\ln(1+x^2y^4z^6)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\alpha}} &,\quad (x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0), \\
0 &, \quad (x,y,z)=(0,0,0)
\end{cases}$$

I want to know for which values of $\alpha\in\Bbb{R}$ the function $f$ is differentiable.

First, I evaluate:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0,0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x,0,0)-f(0,0,0)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln{1}}{x^{2\alpha}}\cdot\frac{1}{x}=0. $$

Similarly,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0,0,0)=0. $$

So, all the partial derivatives in $(0,0,0)$ exists.

All I need to do is to prove that the partial derivatives are continuous. First, looking at the first variable:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y,z)=-2x\frac{\frac{y^4z^6(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{1+x^2y^4z^6}-\alpha\ln(1+x^2y^4z^6)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\alpha+1}} $$

I literally have no idea of how to prove that this function goes to $0$ when $(x,y,z)\rightarrow (0,0,0)$.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried spherical coordinates?

Comment: I tried, but the expression $x^2y^4z^6$ becomes $r^{12}\sin^6\theta\cos^6\theta\sin^4\phi\cos^4\phi$, did not help :(